# Are these sentences by Thomas Kuhn grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, is-it-a-sentence

I'm almost certain that Kuhn would not publish an essay with grammatical mistakes, but those two sentences seem plain wrong to me. (I am not a native speaker.)

> Though my argument does demand that I illustrate them briefly, my
>   views will begin to depart from those long current only after I have
>   done so.

The last part of this sentence sounds just wrong to my ears.

> My critic asserts, however, that there is only one such value of p,
>   that corresponding to objective choice, and he believes that all
>   rational members of the group must arrive at it.

In my opinion the third comma needs to be removed and an "is" needs to be inserted after the second "that".

Comment: They are grammatical.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. Would you mind elaborating why there is not "is" necessary in the second sentence?

Comment: It just elliptically refers to the "one such value of p" from earlier, I think. But someone with more technical knowledge might be able to give you a better or even a more accurate answer than this.

Comment: the second that is equivalent to  "such value of p, _which is the one_ corresponding..."

Comment: @mplungjan- or simply *the one*:  "there is only one such value of p, *the one* corresponding to objective choice"

Comment: I wanted to be absolutely clear

Comment: Please explain what you feel is wrong with the first sentence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, though infelicitous.

> Though my argument does demand that I illustrate them briefly, my views will begin to depart {from those [views that have been] long current} only after I have [illustrated them].
>
> My critic asserts, however, that there is only one such value of p — [namely] that [value] corresponding to objective choice —; and he believes that all rational members of the group must arrive at it.